# Android: Is there an Archive attribute for files?

Tags: android, file

Do files in Android have an Archive attribute like they do in desktop operating systems? This is usually an attribute that indicates that a file has been modified and backup programs can use it to determine which files to backup.

Comment: The only "desktop operating system" that has an archive attribute for files, AFAIK, is Windows.

Comment: Since Android is Linux-based, this may be relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/304087